# How to create custom ISO using autoinstall process in particularly for 21.10

Tags: iso

I am trying to create a custom ISO particularly for 21.10 and successfully created 20.04.* iso using the attached procedure(https://gist.github.com/s3rj1k/55b10cd20f31542046018fcce32f103e) and worked fine with that procedure.
When I try to create a 21.10 custom ISO, I found that there is no /isolinux folder and boot/grub/efi.img file inside the extracted/base iso, and these folder/files are not present even in 20.10, 21.04, and 21.10.
can anyone help if already been implemented?
These folders/files are present in 20.04.* iso's where I tried earlier.

Comment: Ubuntu ISOs are built for multiple architectures; and effort is made to ensure all architectures boot the same **for a given release**.  Ubuntu has changed the way *live* ISOs boot various times since 20.04, yet you seem to expect they'd be the same?  You're working from an invalid assumption.

Comment: I have minimal experience with this, Just I am comparing with working one and the non-working one. Please suggest a way to create a custom iso with 21.10 base iso. Don't know is there another process to create a custom iso after 20.04* releases.

Comment: I would have asked this question on the github page.  See the comments on the page: main comment is that you need to use an original installer. https://gist.github.com/s3rj1k/55b10cd20f31542046018fcce32f103e#comments

Comment: @Rinzwind, Yes, In that link, information related to is only 20.04 LTS release, As you said, Orinial installer means base iso ?, I can't go with the base iso I have to inject my user-data file inside the iso.

Comment: Probably related:  https://askubuntu.com/q/1289400