# Xubuntu custom iso, no isolinux.bin file

Tags: xubuntu

I am trying to make a custom iso from xubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64 but there is no isolinux.bin file after extract. `find` command does not help. Try for yourself. And `genisoimage` says Oh no there is no isolinux.bin file or something like that.

Comment: Are you using appropriate instructions for the release?   Ubuntu has changed the way ISOs boot; with isolinux being *deprecated* and replaced by `grub` so all architectures can boot the same.  All Ubuntu ISOs for a given release will boot the same regardless of architecture, but different ISOs from different releases are no longer identical in how they boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remaster Installation Image for Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289400/remaster-installation-image-for-ubuntu-20-10)